# Are client service contracts still autogenerated in WCF 4.0?

Tags: wcf, wcf-client, nettcpbinding, servicecontract

I have a net.tcp binding example that apparently dates back to .NET 2.0 runtime version. The client code of the WCF Net.TCP binding example has an interface marked as "System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "2.0.x.x") or so.

it also defines some Request & Response classes where the request apparently wraps the parameters of the service operation contract and the Response class wraps the result/return value. And it also defines a controller class for the service.

Now, in a WCF hosted by winform with net.tcp binding, I have found no way to autogenerate these classes myself. I wonder, is that an old way of doing things? is it required? or can I just include in the client app a reference to the DLL that contains the service?

I made some changes and now nothing works and wondered if I can just get rid of those "autogenerated" classes (or if not, HOW can I regenerate them?).

I use Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate for .NET 4.5 under Windows 7 Ultimate. My application are two winforms (client and server) that use WCF with netTCP binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I have to point svcutil o the **base address** rather than that of the service or endpoint. Then it will generate the client code and config.